# deleteSections only remove the last section

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a static table view that contains three section

section 1 contains 1 row

section 2 contains 1 row

section 3 contains 2 row

I have a UISwitch in section 1 that by changing it, section 2 should be removed or insert

As I have static table, I only added `numberOfSections` protocols 
Also I made a array of name of section, just for counting the number of section, nothing more.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if exportDataSwitch.isOn {
        return sections.count - 1
    } else {
        return sections.count
    }
}
```

In the function that will be called after switch is on or off, I wrote these codes

```
@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     if exportDataSwitch.isOn {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteSections([1], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
     } else {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertSections([1], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when I the want to remove section 2 ([1]), I got this error

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

But it works perfectly when I want to remove the last section (section 3 [2]).

I heard that I have to remove the data inside the section first, but when it removes the last section, I didn't remove any data and it works fine. 
could you help me on that? thank you so much

Comment: I'd recommend to convert your static table to dynamic table, and populate it in code. Also if you only have 3 sections you could reconsider using UIStackView instead.

Comment: The op says "I have a static table". As I understood it is probably set statically in a xib file (with prototype cells). I recommended to change to a dynamic way with the "data source" in code as people answered. Removing the 2nd section with a UIStackView would be straightforward (by setting a view.hidden = NO). All in all more straightforward code-wise. The only thing you lose is the scrolling ability (and standard styling, but it is not clear if it is needed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the sections from your dataSource indeed. The table will be constructed again with the same sections as you provide in your array, but if you remove one, the math doesn’t add up.

Also, `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` is not required here but is used when performing multiple updates.

```
@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     if exportDataSwitch.isOn {
        sections.remove(at: 1)
        tableView.deleteSections([1], with: .fade)
     } else {
        sections.insert(“title”, at: 1)
        tableView.insertSections([1], with: .fade)
        }
    }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(section == 0) {
        return 1
    } else if(section == 1) {
        return 1
    } else if(section == 2) {
        return 2
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear Penny, I did what you said but I got the same error, Just keep it in the mind, that I don't use any array to define cells, because It was static, I define all of them in the storyboard, I just used array to for counting and they do not have anything to cells.

Comment: Try again but just return sections.count in the numberOfSections method. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have already tried that, same error. Here is the error in the debug consule: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: As mentioned by Marc, you need to implement numberOfRowsInSection method as well. See my edited answer above for a very simple implementation.

Comment: Thanks dear Penny, I did that, now I got another error in the line tableview.deleteSections...  , here is the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Are you sure the section exists?

Comment: yes I made them in the storyboard, but I dont set the function of cellForRowAt, I thought it was not required for a static table view

Comment: Have you created an IBOutlet for your tableView?

Comment: I have used a TableViewController